# how to get the storage utilization of a table in BigTable

Tags: node.js, bigtable, google-cloud-bigtable

I am trying to distribute the tables I have in my BigTable instance on balanced sets. For that I need to get the table size of each one of the tables that I need to balance (according to storage utilization)

I am using the `"@google-cloud/bigtable": "^0.10.2"` along with nodejs version `v9.11.2`. I have managed to successfully get the array of all table objects from instance using `const [tables] = await instance.getTables();` however when I loop over `tables` I could not find the size or storage utilization of any of its elements

Answer (score 5):

You can use the [Stackdriver Monitoring API](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/api/v3/) via the [Node.jS client library](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/docs/reference/libraries#client-libraries-install-nodejs) to retrieve the `bigtable.googleapis.com/table/bytes_used` metric. This metric is sampled every 60 seconds and there's an approximately 2 minute reporting delay.

See https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/api/metrics_gcp#gcp-bigtable for the full list of metrics published for the Cloud Bigtable service.